# Swift: Crash in Release Build with infix operator/ top level function

Tags: swift, crash, infix-operator

I've created an infix operator in Swift to compare two Optional, Equatable values (something I commonly need to do):

```
infix operator ==? { precedence 130 }
public func ==? <T: Equatable> (lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  if let left = lhs, right = rhs {
    return left == right
  }

  if lhs == nil && rhs == nil {
    return true
  }

  return false
}
```

Pretty simple.

I have a type `User` that utilizes this infix operator as part of it's `Equatable` conformance to `==`:

```
public func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
  if lhs.id != rhs.id {
    return false
  }

  return
    lhs.firstName ==? rhs.firstName &&
    lhs.lastName ==? rhs.lastName &&
    lhs.photoURL ==? rhs.photoURL &&
    lhs.orgID == rhs.orgID
}
```

As you can see, I have a few optional parameters I need to compare to each other using the infix operator.  If I build using `debug` configuration, everything works fine.  However, if I build with `release` configuration, I get this crash (reported via Fabric/Crashlytics):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x4000000000000000`

The stack trace is long, but the relevant crash is occurring here:

```
libswiftCore.dylib      swift_unknownRetain + 16

User.swift line 24    function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded> of static TransportLayer.== infix (TransportLayer.User,  TransportLayer.User) -> Swift.Bool
```

`line 24` corresponds directly with `public func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {`.  If I remove the infix operator `==?`, the crash does not occur.

If I replace the infix operator with a top level function `public func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {...}` (same exact implementation as `==?`), the crash *still* occurs.  So it's not specific to the infix operator.

Again, this is only occurring on release builds under Swift 1.2.  I cannot use Swift 2 because it's not out of beta, so please don't submit that as an answer.

### Update

The problem appears to be module related.  The infix operator and the top level function were defined in a separate module called `Utilities`, which I was importing into the `User.swift` file.  I tried moving the `isEqual` function into the same file and the crash no longer occurs.  But I'd rather have the function in the correct module.